# Ask LSF to allocate immediately

Tags: scheduler, lsf

How to ask LSF to immediately allocate/execute my job without any wait ?

I ve few timebound jobs and I want them to be executed immediately or killed immediately. Are there any way to do the same ?

Comment: You mean like SGE's qsub -now y?

Comment: exactly... Are there any way ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088536/qsub-now-equivalent-using-bsub

Comment: Yes, I am aware of LSF_NIOS_PEND_TIMEOUT but it is a 1 min wait, not exactly line -now=yes of SGE.

Answer (score 0):

You may try brun command. For kill immediately, try bkill